# Need help coming up with hash function algorithm

Tags: algorithm, hash

I'm working on a hash function that gives a given string an "ID" by mapping that string to a key. The algorithm I need to use is described below:

- Given the string `NOTE`, we assign a value to each letter, for example:

  ```
  N = 14, O =15, T = 20, E = 5
  ```
- Then we multiply and add:

  ```
  14 * 32^3 + 15 * 32^2 + 20 * 32^1 + 5 * 32^0
  ```
- By factoring this expression we get:

  ```
  ((14 * 32 + 15) * 32 + 20) * 32 + 5
  ```
- But that value might get too large so we use mod division after each set of parentheses as such:

  ```
  ((14 * 32 + 15)%tableSize *32 + 20)%tableSize * 32 + 5
  ```

How can I create an algorithm to accomplish this? I have tried to do it but my implementation is extremely inefficient. My professor said it shouldn't be longer than 7 lines. Can anyone offer suggestions on how to efficiently implement the above algorithm?

My algorithm in case anyone cares is:

```
int HashDictionary::getKey(string word) const{
    int wordLength = word.length();
    int* values = new int[wordLength];
    for ( int i = 0; i < wordLength; i++ ) {
        values[i] = int(word[i]);
    }

    int productSoFar = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < wordLength;i++){
        productSoFar *= 32;

        if(i == 0){
            productSoFar = values[i] * 32;
            productSoFar = productSoFar + values[i+1];
            productSoFar %= tableSize;
            i++;
        }
        else{
            productSoFar += values[i];
            productSoFar %= tableSize;
        }

    }
    delete [] values;
    return productSoFar;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have an `i++` inside the `if()` condition? Also, are you using C#?

Comment: Why not just use something like CRC32?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need 2 loops; since the only thing the first does is translate the characters to integers, you can just translate each as you need it, and avoid the values array entirely.  That should speed things up AND reduce your line count.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int HashDictionary::getKey(string word) const{
    int wordLength = word.length();
    int* values = new int[wordLength];
    values[0] = int(word[0]);
    values[1] = int(word[1]);

    int productSoFar = 0;
    productSoFar = values[0] * 32;
    productSoFar = productSoFar + values[1];
    productSoFar %= tableSize;

    for(int i = 1; i < wordLength;i++){
        productSoFar *= 32;
        productSoFar += values[i];
        productSoFar %= tableSize;
        values[i] = int(word[i]);
        }
    delete [] values;
    return productSoFar;
}
```